# Correct syntax to insert if not exist or update if exist SQL

Tags: php, sql

I need a push to get working a IF EXIST UPDATE else, INSERT, below is my function that update the database:

```
function _updatePrices($data){
    $connection     = _getConnection('core_write');
    $sku            = $data[0];
    $price          = $data[1];
    $attribute_id   = '76';
    $websiteId      = $data[2];
    $productId      = _getIdFromSku($sku);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_decimal') . "
            (entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
            VALUES (4, ".$attribute_id.", ".$websiteId.", ".$productId.", ".$price.")
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            value = (".$price.")";
            "WHERE attribute_id = ".$attribute_id."
            AND entity_id = ".$productId."
            AND store_id = ".$websiteId."
            ";
    $connection->query($sql);
}
```

How can i declare the values to be inserted ?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `on duplicate key UPDATE`

More info here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: mmm, what i want is if entity_id has no value or does not exist in that table Insert it with the entity_id and value.

Comment: it seems that you are looking to update if the entity ID exists. Can you make this part of a composite key or make it the primary key of the table?

Comment: I have updated the question with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Answer (score 2):

The correct method is:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`columns here`) VALUES ('values here')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `column`=VALUES(`column`), `col2`=VALUES(`col2`)...
```

Comment: this part i cannot understand very well `column`=VALUES(`column`), `col2`=VALUES(`col2`)...

Comment: It's basically like ``UPDATE `table` SET [values stuff here] WHERE [duplicate key condition here]``. The `VALUES()` function returns the value that would have been inserted, useful for multi-insert queries, but also to avoid duplication.

Comment: I understand, i have edited the question with the updated function, can you please tell me why im getting SQLSTATE[42000] ?